# Alterar exibição de acordo com opção do <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, html5-video

Estou montando um Menu de seleção onde o usuário seleciona um mês, quando o mês é selecionado, é exibido um próximo menu de seleção para escolher um dia. O que preciso fazer agora é: quando o usuário selecionar o dia, é exibido um video. No caso, há um video predefinido para cada dia.

A função .js que tenho é:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var arquivos = {
        Janeiro: ["./videos/1.mp4", "./videos/2.mp4", "./videos/3.mp4", "./videos/4.mp4"],
        Fevereiro: ["./videos/5.mp4", "./videos/6.mp4", "./videos/7.mp4", "./videos/8.mp4"],
    }

var dias = {
    Janeiro: ["Dia 6", "Dia 13", "Dia 20", "Dia 27"],
    Fevereiro: ["Dia 3", "Dia 10", "Dia 17", "Dia 24"],
}

$("#mes").change(function() {
    var selecionado = this.value;
    var html = arquivos[selecionado].reduce(function(str, arquivos){
        return str + '<option value="' + dias + '">' + dias + '</option>';
    }, '');
})
});
```

Esta é a tag do video que cada  do menu Dia deve retornar:

```
<video class="borda-player" src="' + arquivos + '" width="56%" controls></video>
```

E por fim, esta é a base no html:

```
<select name="dias" id="mes" class="selecao">
   <option value="Janeiro">Janeiro</option>
   <option value="Fevereiro">Fevereiro</option>
   <option value="Março">Março</option>
</select>
<select id="diaSelecionado" class="selecao"></select>
```

O resultado final deveria ser assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ajude-me, por gentileza!

Answer (score -1):

Vamos lá,

```js
// Jquery básico
$( document ).ready(function(){
    // Mesmos dados anteriores, mas organizados de forma diferente
 var data = {
  'Janeiro' : [
      ['Dia 6','./videos/1.mp4'],
      ['Dia 13','./videos/2.mp4'],
      ['Dia 20','./videos/3.mp4'],
      ['Dia 27','./videos/4.mp4']
     ],
  'Fevereiro' : [
      ['Dia 3','./videos/5.mp4'],
      ['Dia 10','./videos/6.mp4'],
      ['Dia 17','./videos/7.mp4'],
      ['Dia 24','./videos/8.mp4']
     ]     
 }
 
// Mês selecionado
$("#mes").change(function() {
 // Captura o valor selecionado
 var selecionado = $("#mes option:selected").val();;
 
 // Restringe os valores para dias
 var days = data[selecionado];
 
 // Adiciona options a segundo select
 $.each(days,function(index, val){
  ("#diaSelecionado").append($('<option>'),{
   text: val[0],
   value: val[1]
  })
 });
 
 // Quando o dia é selecionado
 $('#diaSelecionado").change(function() {
  // Modifica o src da tag video
  $('video').attr(
   'src': $("#diaSelecionado option:selected").val();
  );
  
  // Carrega o video
  $("video")[0].load();
 }
}) 
})
```

Tentei deixar o JS o mais organizado possível e sendo sincero, não pude testar o mesmo então é bem possível que haja erros, porém já serve para lhe dar uma boa base.

Recomendo que leia um pouco mais sobre o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) para realizar um projeto assim. Qualquer duvidas estamos ai, espero ter ajudado ou ao menos dado uma luz :D

Comment: Valeu demais Victor! Vou ler a respeito e usar seu codigo como base! Valeu mesmo!!